# Fence Post Errors When Displaying Arrays

Tags: c++

I am currently using C++ on a program called CodeZinger for one of my classes. I was asked to make a program that will output an array with input that the program gives me.
See screenshot below.

[image]

The issue is that the program outputs an extra space at the end of my array, which is making the program say that I have not gotten the question right.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rows = 1;
    int cols = 1;
    long int arr[100][100];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

My output (see screenshot above) is showing that my code is right and it was going well, except for that extra space at the end. Is there any way to remove that extra space without adding an if statement into my code somewhere?

Comment: Have the inner loop iterate until `j < cols - 1` and then write one more output line after it ends, without a space (e.g.: `std::cout << arr[i][cols-1];`)

Comment: If you can guarantee that `cols` is at least 1, then you don't need an `if` using what's in the above comment. In your code you do not show how `rows` and `cols` are initialized, so it's impossible for say for sure.

Comment: You never seem to initialize `rows` and `cols`, and therefore their values will be *indeterminate* and using those values will lead to *undefined behavior*. Is the code you show truly a proper [mre]?

Comment: Please paste your _exact code_ into your question.  The code in this question and the code in your screenshot differ in several significant ways.  There's a missing `;` and missing variable initialization.

Comment: When I set int cols = 1; it still shows it as the same output with the same fencepost error. @ChrisMM

Comment: @DrewDormann Unfortunately Codezinger will send an error if I try to copy and paste, due to the website not allowing us to copy and paste due to not wanting us to cheat using someone else's programs.

Comment: @Daniel, in combination with UnholySheep's comment, is what I had meant.

Comment: I rewrote my program in order to fit the criteria of a debug program that can be used outside of the codezinger website.

Comment: The best way to debug programs is by building and running them locally on your own system. So-called "competition" or "online judge" sites that disallows copy-pasting makes that very hard. Not to mention that many of them doesn't tell you the input, or the expected output when a program fails, making it very hard to debug anyway. In short: Don't use such sites to learn the basics of programming, programming languages, or computer science in general.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The problem with that is that I HAVE to use it for this class. If I do not use it, I cannot submit my work. I ran this on Visual Studio, but when I put this same code into Codezinger, I got the issue of it saying my output was incorrect and it sucks honestly because I have to use this program specifically for this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the inner loop iterate until j < cols - 1 and then write one more output line after it ends, without a space (e.g.: std::cout << arr[i][cols-1];) –
UnholySheep